# No font in emacs on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, emacs

When I open emacs over an SSH connection I get this error

```
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-courier-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*--*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
```

and the font is replaced with empty squares.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd guess it's a missing font that got replaced, heh, with squares (whether this is the "closest" font or not, I don't know, and YMMV).

For a quick fix, if you have `xfontsel` in the remote system, you can use that to check for an available font (select it in `xfontsel`, then hit "Select" to copy it to the [selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection), and paste it in another X application (click with the middle mouse button))  and then try `emacs -fn fontspec` where `fontspec` is the string built by `xfontsel`.

Fixing this would probably involve installing the missing fonts in the remote computer, so that emacs can use these fonts (I guess it's something like adobe-fonts? look for that kind of package in the remote system package manager (if you have an account with UID=0 there, of course, otherwise either you ask the administrator, or you have to use a workaround)).

If you want to change the emacs font like above, you can put that in `~/.Xdefaults`. I'd not be surprised if you could do the same in `~/.emacs`.

Comment: How do I get the name of the font from `xfontsel`?

Comment: Right, I forgot that, there's the "select" button on the top left corner that copies the font name to the "selection clipboard", just hitting the middle mouse button inside another X window with text input should paste it.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem. I ran `xfontsel` which came up with a single available font. I set it up in my `.emacs` file `(set-default-font "-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-medium-r-normal--17-120-100-100-m-0-adobe-standard")`, but it didn't solve the problem. It still looks exactly the same. I changed `.Xdefaults` to contain `xterm*VT100*font:-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-medium-r-normal--17-120-100-100-m-0-adobe-standard`, and no difference. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Put it into your ~/.Xdefaults such as:

```
emacs*font: -*-fixed-medium-r-normal-*-15-*-100-100-*-*-iso8859-*
```

Then merge it to the X resource database with:

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is basic, the Fonts are not present in your SSH client system

Just install the Xming extra fonts

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/files/Xming-fonts/7.5.0.70/

Then restart every thing .. Should work