# User installation emacs 23 on a centos 5 with system-wide installed emacs-21.4-20.el5?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, software-installation, emacs, upgrade

I would like to install my own copy of emacs 23 on a Centos 5 Linux where I don't have admin rights. I would like to have my own modern copy of emacs on this Centos 5 system since I've got a problem with the [fonts when running emacs-21 through an ssh connection to a Centos 5 Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31002/no-font-in-emacs-on-centos), while my local system is a more modern Ubuntu 12.04.2.

I am not used to rpm systems and less so on systems with no admin rights. Any good tutotials on how to install my own copy of emacs 23 on this system?

```
uname -a
Linux xxx-xxxx-xxx 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Thu Sep 3 03:28:30 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

rpm -qa | grep emacs\-2 
emacs-21.4-20.el5
```

Comment: compile it. `./configure --prefix "$HOME/local" --without-x; make; make install`.

Comment: You'll have to run it by `~/local/bin/emacs` (or create an alias in your shell). BTW, you might run into trouble if development libraries aren't installed. Perhaps ask the friendly sysadmin to do a system-wide installation into `/usr/local`?

Comment: @jordanm: I've got have it compiled against X windows, since I want to be able to bring up an X window emacs session.